# Extract routes from the request header using express middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express backend server serving at the following endpoint

```
app.get('/entities/:entityId', showEntity)
```

later when I do `GET /entities/123`. I know the route is `/entities/123` from `req.url`

But is there a way that I can setup a middleware that gives me `/entities/:entityId`?  This way I can know it's `this` route that is doing something?

p.s: I want to setup endpoint permission checking in case you wanna know why I do this.

Comment: ok I think I have found it `req.route.path` is what I want...

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try something like this

```
var securityCheck = function(req,res,next){
   if(req.session.auth){
      next();
   } else {
      res.status(403).json(null);
   }
}

app.get('/entities/:entityId',securityCheck,showEntity)
```

Comment: I am doing something more complicated. Say user A in entity 1 has `read` entity role can do `showEntity` and user B in entity 2 has `developer` entity role can do `showEntity`. And each entity manages his own entity roles.